# Git upload project full site

Tags: php, git, upload, codeigniter-3

I am new for using Github. I want upload my full site in new Repository in Github.com. But Github just can upload not more than 100file, and I'm download codeigniter-3 it's have 253file (original without my new file).
Can I upload my project in to Github?

Comment: how are you uploading the files?

Comment: I am create new repository, then make name for my repository,then next than drag and drop my project to from upload in github. Then say 'Yowza, that’s a lot of files. Try again with fewer than 100 files.' @Gordon

Comment: This might be a limitation with the drag and drop uploader then. Use the command line client instead.

Comment: where to using the command line client?  @Gordon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is likely a limitation of the drag and drop interface. I'd suggest to get familiar with the command line client instead. It's much more convenient than using the web interface and you'll need it anyway if you want to do serious work on that project from your dev machine.

First clone your project to a local directory:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

Then from your project directory, add all the files:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git push origin master
```

Alternatively, consider using https://desktop.github.com/

Reference:

- https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/
- https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-from-the-command-line/

Comment: thank you. Using drag and drop have limit access. I must install git first, then try this. @Gordon

Answer (score 2):

GitHub upload file step by step follow.

1. Now first create account on github.

https://github.com/login

2. create repository in your GitHub account.
3. setup git directory on your project directory by GIT Clone.
   after git clone setup .GIT directory on your project with config.

   Example: ##Config git repository##

> git clone https://github.com/username/repository

```
   ##upload project on GIT##
```

> ```
>   git add /your-folder
>
>    git commit -m 'your first commit'
>
>    git push -u origin master
> ```

after push successfully upload your project.

Comment: What meaning upload project can using drag and drop from my local directory to form upload file in Github? or must using command line to? @pawansen

Comment: You must use command line, and import project on repository help Reference.    https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/    @Stfvns